# Python GUI Toolkit for Text-Based Game?

Tags: python, user-interface, text-based

Quick to learn is pretty important, but I need just some basic GUI tools, for Ubuntu OS but would be nice to have multi-OS compatibility. Any suggestions?

The basic dynamics of the intended game just include a text input and some set reaction
frames.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is a set reaction frame?

Comment: I guessed it means sprites drawn to coincide with the text-based interactions, but I agree some additional details would be nice, as that would take it beyond text-based.

Answer (score 3):

You can give the game a little more flavor if you use [Ren'Py](http://www.renpy.org/) rather than doing it all yourself.

Comment: Great link! I hadn't seen that before!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean with text-based menus and graphics as well?

curses is included in the standard Python distribution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses
http://docs.python.org/library/curses.html

But perhaps that is **too** text-based?

Answer (score 0):

For basic toolkit, I think tkinter which comes with python is okay. If you want to have graphical toolkit with more functionality, I would suggest you to take a look at wxpython which is cross-platform compatible.